# Why and how is this transparent portion shown as opaque in iPhone App?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, png

Please check below image.

[image]

If you see, below the black outline of the blue speech bubble, there is a skybluish portion shown.
I am using a transparent png for the blue speech bubble. So, not sure from where this skyblue portion comes.

Please is the transparent PNG of the speech bubble that I use.

[image]

What is wrong here?

```
 UIView* popoverView1;
 UIViewController* popoverContent;
    UIImageView *imagebackground;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPopoverController *pc;

popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
        popoverView1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(56,0,393,444)];
       // popoverView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        imagebackground = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,393,444)];
        [imagebackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"card-creation-screen15.png"]];
        [popoverView1 addSubview:btndone];
        [popoverView1 addSubview:btn];
        popoverContent.view = popoverView1;
        [btndone setHidden:YES];

        [popoverView1 addSubview:imagebackground];
        [popoverView1 bringSubviewToFront:btn];
        [popoverView1 bringSubviewToFront:btndone];


        popoverController.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        popoverView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(393, 444);
        pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc]                                                 initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
        [pc presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(20,650,131,131) inView:self.view                                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                          animated:YES];
        pc.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 popoverController.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    popoverView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    pc.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Where's the relevant code?

Comment: Have you tried setting the background color of your imageview (imagebackground)?

Comment: Yes, i gave it clear color

Comment: I could not find that in the shown code. That's why I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your popoverview1 view has a white `backgroundColor`, that should be `[UIColor clearColor];` in any case - you also see a small white border on top of your image because of that. Where the gradient comes from I can't explain from the information you gave.

Comment: You should change your example code then, it still shows whiteColor.

Comment: By the way: The image you show is  not the image that is used in the screenshot - it's flipped horizontally. Are you sure you use the right image?

Comment: Second By The Way: You do realise that the popover controller has an arrow of its own, which is shown additionally to the arrow in your image? Maybe you should drop the popover idea as a whole and just implement it as a UIView that you show on top of your main view, maybe even as a UIViewController used in the main view controller (look up 'container')?